# Conversion from bool to int (true -> 1 and false -> 0)

Tags: f#

Is there any built-in way in F# to convert from `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`? This is simple in languages like C, C++ etc.

As a bit of background I am trying to solve an exercise in a textbook (exercise 2.4 in [Functional Programming Using F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107684064)), which asks for an F# function `occFromIth(str,i,ch)` that returns the number of occurrences of character `ch` in positions `j` in the string `str` with `j >= i`.

My solution is

```
let rec occFromIth (str : string, i, ch) =
    if i >= str.Length then 0
    else if i < 0 || str.[i] <> ch then occFromIth(str, i+1, ch)
    else 1 + occFromIth(str, i+1, ch)
```

but I don't like the code duplication so I wrote

```
let boolToInt = function
    | true -> 1
    | false -> 0

let rec occFromIth (str : string, i, ch) =
    if i >= str.Length then 0
    else boolToInt (not (i < 0 || str.[i] <> ch)) + occFromIth(str, i+1, ch)
```

I guess another alternative is to use `if... then... else...`, in the style of the C/C++ [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx)

```
let rec occFromIth (str : string, i, ch) =
    if i >= str.Length then 0
    else (if (not (i < 0 || str.[i] <> ch)) then 1 else 0) + occFromIth(str, i+1, ch)
```

or

```
let rec occFromIth (str : string, i, ch) =
    if i >= str.Length then 0
    else (if (i < 0 || str.[i] <> ch) then 0 else 1) + occFromIth(str, i+1, ch)
```

What is the way to do this in F#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cew9dz7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: @m-y thanks, I did try that in F# interactive but couldn't get it to work. What is the right syntax and is this the "most F#" way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`System.Convert.ToInt32(bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cew9dz7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1) -- I'm not too familiar with F#, but I believe that using a function is the same whether it is built in or not: function(arg0, arg1, ...). So, in this case you'd simply call `System.Convert.ToInt32(myBool)`.

Comment: thanks in F# interactive, `System.Convert.ToInt32(true);;` yields `val it : int = 1`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need the bool to int or int to bool as you can achieve the result as:

```
let occFromIth (str : string, i, ch) =
    str 
    |> Seq.mapi (fun j c -> (j,c))
    |> Seq.filter (fun (j,c) -> j >= i && c = ch)
    |> Seq.length
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately as I'm a beginner I'm not 100% sure what's going on here. I know that `|>` passes an argument from left to right, so it looks like it's a LINQ-style expression, first creating a sequence of (index, character), then filtering that sequence to match the index and character conditions, and finally counting the filtered sequence?

Answer (score -2):

There is difference in making a function or using build in. The CPU instruction of any comparison return a result translated to the bit pattern for 1 and 0. This can be used to make branchless programming, which dependend on the situation are more effecient then branching. Comparison of to values can be found without branching

```
   Int min(int a, int b) {
         Int temp = a < b;
         Return a*temp + b*(1-temp);
   }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to have anything to do with [tag:f#].

Comment: just because I used another language didn't it mean that it doesn't apply to F# too. The code would just be less readable because I had to do a lot of work around to avoid FSharps type system